# How to manipulate large `RasterStack` object and write all raster grid in plain-text data in R?

Tags: r, raster, data-manipulation

I have faced several challenges when I am dealing with very large `RasterStack` object in R. Here is the main story, I have downloaded gridded data from European Climate Assessment website([download site of gridded data](https://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/downloadchunks.php) and [download link of gridded data that I am interested in](https://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/data/Grid_0.25deg_reg/tg_0.25deg_reg_1995-2010_v17.0.nc.gz)). So my very first step was importing this data in R as `RasterStack` object. Then I intended to crop raster grid of only particular countries, so I used `raster::crop` to do that. My ultimate goal is to calculate the annual average temperature for each grid cell. Here is the grid coverage that I cropped from original raw `RasterStack` object where grid resolution is defined as `0.25-degree` resolution:

[image]

Here is the R script that I took a shot:

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
library(R.utils)
library(maptools)

raw_netCDF = raster::stack("~/tg_0.25deg_reg_1995-2010_v17.0.nc")     # read downloaded gridded data in R
data(wrld_simpl) 
Germany <- wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl@data$NAME == "Germany",]
deu_ext <- extent(Germany)
Germany_ <- crop(raw_netCDF, deu_ext)
```

but above cropped solution `Germany_` raised a challenge. The first challenge is treating missing values in large `RasterStack` object. If I didn't treat missing values in large `RasterStack` object, in newly produced cropped raster grid, all missing values were turned into zero, which cause confusion to read temperature observation such as zero Celsius degree. So I treated missing values in large `RasterStack` object in two different way. The first one is down below:

```
raw_netCDF_ = raster::reclassify(raw_netCDF , cbind(NA, -999))
```

but `raster::reclassify` always failed because of memory problem. so it is not good solution. I tried `raster::calc` to treat missing values in very large `RasterStack` object but it is extremely slow even I run the same operation in a powerful computer. So using `raster::calc` to treat missing values is really not a good idea. Here is R script down below

```
raw_netCDF_  = raster::calc(raw_netCDF , function(x) { ifelse(is.na(x), -999, x) })
```

I want to do simple statistics, to calculate an annual mean temperature for each grid cell for whole grid coverage above, and produce its output in clean and simple plaintext data. In final raster grid data in plain text only contain grid coordinate and it's annual mean temperature. Doing such operation for `RasterStack` object is not an ordinary task for me.

Perhaps, there must be a possible optimal solution to properly manipulate very large `RasterStack` object and make sure all missing values in original raw data can be correctly preserved in the cropped raster grid of Germany.

**Desired output**:

In exported plain text data, I want to have annual mean `Temp` for whole Germany grid for 16 years something like this:

```
> ann_mean_temp_1996_1999
        long    lat net_1996_precip net_1997_temp net_1997_temp net_1998_temp net_1999_temp net_2000_temp
   1:  6.125 47.375      84.4         86.4         83.4         81.4         80.4         87.4
   2:  6.375 47.375      89.3         88.3         84.3         81.3         846.3         846.3
   3:  6.625 47.375      80.0         85.0         80.0         83.0         88.0         87.0
   4:  6.875 47.375      84.4         83.4         85.4         86.4         82.4         80.4
   5:  7.125 47.375      83.0         85.0         84.0         89.0         83.0         84.0
  ---                                                                                               
1112: 13.875 54.875      63.8         68.8         66.8         67.8         65.8         66.8
1113: 14.125 54.875      69.6         65.6         61.6         60.6         62.6         63.6
1114: 14.375 54.875      60.5         61.5         62.5         67.5         69.5         64.5
1115: 14.625 54.875      62.9         67.9         68.9         67.9         64.9         68.9
1116: 14.875 54.875      64.6         67.6         66.6         62.8         64.6         63.5
```

If manipulating very large `RasterStack` object in R is possible, how can I obtain expected raster grid data with correct resolution (missing values would be properly treated) and apply simple statistics for all daily temperature observation for each grid? How can I make this happen? Is that possible to manipulate `RasterStack` object and write all raster grid data in plain text data (`ASCII` or `csv`) in R? Any efficient way to get this task done? Any more thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would object to your notion that this is a "very large" `RasterStack`, but besides that I think what you want to do should be straight forward.

So first I load and crop the data to the extent of Germany:

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
library(R.utils)
library(maptools)



r <- stack('tg_0.25deg_reg_1995-2010_v17.0.nc')

data(wrld_simpl) 

Germany <- wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl@data$NAME == "Germany",]

r_crop <- crop(r,Germany)

#Let's take a look:

plot(r_crop[[1]])
plot(Germany,add=T)
```

The boundary shape isn't particularly pretty, but it does the job. Also, you can see that in the north, the values with NoData are still properly indicated as such:

```
r_crop[[1]][1,1]
# NA
```

[image]

In the next steps, I just use the layer names to extract the years, and then use `lapply` to calculate the means for each year:

```
nms <- names(r_crop)
yrs <- unique(sub('X(\\d+).+','\\1',nms))

yrs[1]
# [1] "1995"

annual_means <- lapply(yrs,function(x) mean(r_crop[[grep(x,nms)]],na.rm=TRUE))
```

This will give you a list called `annual_means` with a raster per year, representing the annual mean for that year. Now you can either stack them back together (with `do.call(stack,annual_means)`), process them individually, or as you probably want to do is write them to disk as csv:

```
# first take a look

plot(annual_means[[1]])
```

[image]

```
# write to disk

write.table(as.matrix(annual_means[[1]]),'ANNUAL_MEAN_TEMP_1995.csv',quote = F,row.names = F,col.names = F,sep = ';')
```

**Edit**:

`annual_means` is a list with a raster per element representing the mean temperature calculated from the daily observations of the original dataset. So the list will have as many elements as there are years.

The `write.table` example above was only shown for one of these years, meaning if that is the output you would like, you would need to replicate the step for all elements of the list.

What the `write.table` step does, is just converting the raster to a matrix, and writing it to disk. The result will be a matrix with as many rows and columns as the raster itself, with each cell separated by a semicolon (my personal preference).

---

**Edit2:**

Just to illustrate my comments from above:

You have 16 years of data, as seen in the `yrs` vector:

```
yrs
 #[1] "1995" "1996" "1997" "1998" "1999" "2000" "2001" "2002" "2003" "2004"
#[11] "2005" "2006" "2007" "2008" "2009" "2010"
```

Now, `annual_means` is a list of length 16, with a single layer raster per year, which is the mean for the entire year calculated for the whole of Germany from the daily data.

Here's an example output:

```
annual_means[[1]]
# class       : RasterLayer 
# dimensions  : 31, 37, 1147  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
# extent      : 5.75, 15, 47.25, 55  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
# data source : in memory
# names       : layer 
# values      : 3.329288, 11.32734  (min, max)
```

As you can see the raster has a resolution of 0.25 degree (which is the original resolution of your data), that results in a raster with 31 rows and 37 columns covering Germany.

To get your desired output:

I'll first name the list entries with the respective years, to make it a bit more visible (you could skip this):

```
names(annual_means) <- yrs
```

Now I will extract the coordinates for each raster and create a dataframe with the values (using `lapply` to iterate over the list):

```
result <- lapply(annual_means, function(x) data.frame(long = coordinates(x)[,1],lat = coordinates(x)[,2],temp_mean =x[]))
```

Now we can inspect the top of the dataframe for e.g. year 2000:

```
head(result$`2000`)

#   long    lat  temp_mean
# 1 5.875 54.875       NaN
# 2 6.125 54.875       NaN
# 3 6.375 54.875       NaN
# 4 6.625 54.875       NaN
# 5 6.875 54.875       NaN
# 6 7.125 54.875       NaN
```

As you can see, the first pixels are all NoData (just like seen in the plot), which is what you want.

So in the end, `result` is a list with each element being a dataframe for a specific year, containing the columns `long`, `lat` and `temp_mean`.

To 100% replicate your desired output, one could now loop again over the `result` list to change the `temp_mean` column name to a year specific one (this is totally optional):

```
for (i in seq_along(result)){

  colnames(result[[i]])[3] <- paste0('Net_',names(result)[i],'_Temp')

}
```

Giving you:

```
head(result$`2000`)

#    long    lat  Net_2000_Temp
# 1 5.875 54.875            NaN
# 2 6.125 54.875            NaN
# 3 6.375 54.875            NaN
# 4 6.625 54.875            NaN
# 5 6.875 54.875            NaN
# 6 7.125 54.875            NaN
```

**Edit3:**

To obtain one dataframe with all the means, you can do this:

```
ann_mean_temp_1996_1999 <- cbind(result[[1]][,1:2],do.call(cbind,lapply(result,function(x) x[,3])))

colnames(ann_mean_temp_1996_1999)[3:ncol(ann_mean_temp_1996_1999)]<- unlist(lapply(result,function(x) colnames(x)[3]))
```

The first `lapply` binds the long/lat (which doesn't change for all years) together with the 3rd column of every list item (which is the T-MEAN).

The second `lapply` extracts and assigns the column names again for the temperatures, which seem to get lost in the process. There's probably a more elegant solution for this than using `lapply` two times, but it does the job.

Comment: I tried your solution on gridded dataset ([download link of original gridded data](https://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/data/Grid_0.25deg_reg/tg_0.25deg_reg_1995-2010_v17.0.nc.gz)), and in exported `ANNUAL_MEAN_TEMP_1995.csv`, coordinate (`long-lat pair`) were missing, and it is quite hard to understand exported `csv` data. Is that possible to refine your solution please? Would it be possible for you to produce more precise and finer solution? Thank you

Comment: @Andy.Jian my solution worked with the gridded data you're linking to, which represents daily temperature observations from 1995 to recent years. `annual_means` represents a list where _each_ element is a mean annual temperature for as specific year, over entire Germany. So a each grid cell represents a mean for that specific year.

Comment: @Andy.Jian You don't need to set a projection for `r_crop` ... it's directly taken from the full dataset `r`. And using `r_ext <- extent(Germany); r_crop <- crop(r,deu_ext)` is going to give you the same result as my approach ... it's just an extra step, which isn't necessary. Maybe it's just a bit more verbose.

Comment: @Andy.Jian apologies for not being clear enough ... I'll edit my solution with more explanation. I hope my previous comment clears up the cropping

Comment: How can I obtain my desired output that added in my updated post? Shouldn't I treat missing value first before do crop? Would it be possible to refine your solution? Thank you!

Comment: so far your updated solution works great unless I have one more question. Why annual mean of some grid has `NaN`? Why does it happen? Any idea?

Comment: These are the no data pixels in the north (probably over ocean) which have no valid observations and are therefore NaN

Comment: @Andy.Jian Some list and dataframe magic will do the trick. Please see my most recent edits.

Comment: I also tried `res = lapply(1:length(result),function(x){return(mutate(result[[x]],id=x))}) %>% 
    bind_rows() %>% 
    spread(key = id,value = temp_mean)`, quite close to my expected output. How can I refine its `temp_mean` column name? Thank you !

Comment: Seems like you're using `dplyr` or similar ... I'm just guessing here, but if you modify the column names beforehand and then use the year or column name as `id` in `mutate`? Anyways, the solution I posted in my update does exactly what you need.

Comment: Glad it helped!